# SAR data for water body extraction

Tags: insar

Is there anyone who can help me with SAR data. I am a beginner with this. Any tutorial/links will help.

Answer (score 3):

This is a fairly broad question but I guess a good place to start would be with Sentinel-1 satellite imagery. Sentinel-1 is a C-band radar platform that operates at 5.405 GHz.

I have incorporated it into water body detection for a number of research projects and if done correctly it can offer good results. The good thing is the data can be downloaded for free from a number of platforms and ESA (The European space Agency) have SNAP (Sentinel Application Platform) which can be used to run a wide range of analysis on the data if you so wish. This is also free.

With this in mind the below tutorial should give you everything you need, or at least give you a very good start.

http://www.un-spider.org/advisory-support/recommended-practices/recommended-practice-flood-mapping/step-by-step

Comment: Thanks.. going through the link.. will come back in case of further doubts.

Comment: I went through  the link and it was really helpful.
Just one small doubt - how do we check the back scatter values from the image? Say if i have to extract water body how do we know the scattering values?

Comment: That again is a good question and there is a lot of literature on that topic. It is fairly hard to say because it can vary from sensor to sensor, due to the environment and the water feature you are trying to map. Manjusree et al. (2012), found optimum thresholds at -8 to -12 dB for HH, -15 to -24 dB for HV and VH and -6 to -15 dB for VV. In my experience VV polarization is best for calm surface water bodies. If you want to find the optimum threshold for your scene then I'm afraid you will have to compare it with in situ measurements or higher resolution multispectral data.

Comment: ok got it.. so we cant get the pixel scattering value from the image?

Comment: Not unless you know for certain what are water features in the SAR image... if you did then you could take samples from the image and set a threshold range the matches that. In a real world scenario (like real time flood mapping) this is not feasible because of time constraints and the fact that you will not know what is a water body or not (that's why you are mapping it).

Comment: Is there any other tutorial/link apart form the other?

Comment: Not that I can think of. You will just have to have a look yourself. http://www.itc.nl/library/papers_2016/msc/wrem/cliu.pdf... This masters thesis offers a good oversight by Liu (2016)

Comment: Thanks.. Wanted something with explanation in software like the UN-spider link. Thats not working for now. If you have any of those, please forward it to me. Meanwhile I am also checking out.